# Mouseenter and Mouseleave function in jquery

Tags: jquery

i have div box. i want when user hover it or mouseenter then next div should display and when user mouseout the visible div should fadeout. my function not working correctly.

```
<head>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">  

$(function (){      

    $('.box').bind({            
        mouseenter: function (){                
            $(this).next().fadeIn('fast')               
        },          
        mouseout: function (){
            $(this).next().fadeOut('fast')                  
        }


        })      
    })    
</script>    

<style>

body { margin:0}
.box { height:300px; width:300px; background:#F00}

.boxcaption { width:300px; height:300px; background:#00F; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; display:none}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrap">

<div class="box"></div>
<div class="boxcaption"></div>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: The problem is that the next element is positioned right above the target, and once you make it appear, you're "leaving" the original element and hovering the new one (which fires fadeOut again)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second element is over the first element.  So when you're mouseentering and then it fades it in, it's seeing an immediate mouseout which is why it's fading. Move your second element down 300 px and you'll see that it works.

Comment: And if you need to show it in its place, then wrap those two in another container, and bind to events on that container (then the element that appers won't fire mouseleave)